# Rebooting a Remote Computer in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to reboot a remote computer by button click.
I have been checking multiple posts and i've tried numerous different Process.Start methods but none seem to work.

Most posts just say use this:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-r -f -m" + BxSD.Text + "-t 00");
```

But i've tried this and variations of it, but all that happens is the cmd window opens for a second then closes and nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I found out that it could not reboot the device based on the hostname and can only reboot by IP address only.
The final iteration of my command is as follows:
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k SHUTDOWN /r /f /m \\" + BxSD.Text);

But now however, the cmd prompt window doesn't exit after sending the command.
Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't reboot an arbitrary remote computer. The remote computer must be configured to allow remote shutdown, and you must have administrative access to it. See the manual steps here for an example. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-remote-shutdown-computer-windows-10

Comment: Just execute the command in the command line, and you will see what error you get.

Comment: The computer(s) I am trying to reach I do have admin access and they all have remote shutdown allowed. I can run these commands fine through command prompt, but also, you can't run this command line for line in command prompt, the syntax is different.

Comment: `Process.Start` is a bit of an anti-pattern because you never know what is acceptable and determining the outcome problematic.  Also it is a _"last-ditch effort"_.   Consider using WMI or equivalent WIN32 api low-level call where rich information is used both in inputs but also the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Process process = new();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new()
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $" ___your command here___ ",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "runas"
            };
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```